# jquery interactive popup windows

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

Can any one provide link for jquery pop window (not div element) plugin. Window should open on mouse over/click events with loading image on link before window open. No light box is required.

Example : infolink urls  for advertisement

Comment: Seems like window.open and no need of jQuery http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Hey!!!  I know all about window.open.  But here I want to make interactive pop up window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to interact with the child and the parent window using javascript, then perhaps you should look into `window.opener` property from the child to call parents global JS function. Like
In parent and child window define a global function
`function Connector(msg){

$('body').append(msg+'<br/>');

}`

From parent, save the window instance that you open
`var child = window.open('child.html');`
after the window is open [you'll have to figure it out how to wait for that] call
`child.Connector('parent calling child');`

Similarly, from the child call `Connector()` function in the parent of the child window like
`window.opener.Connector('child calling parent');`

Hope this helps you, below is the html and JS I used
For the Parent html

```
function Connector(msg){
    $('body').append(msg+'
');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  var child = null;
  $('#test_btn').bind('click', function(){
    var newwin = window.open('new_wind.html');
    $('#call_child').show();
    child = newwin;
    if(window.console){
        console.log($child.contents().find('body').length);
        console.log(newwin);
        console.log($child);
    }

    return false;
  });
  $('#call_child').bind('click', function(){
    if(child){
        child.Connector('parent calling child');
    }
  });
});
```

`

Hello World

`

For the child:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if(window.opener){
            window.opener.Connector('child calling parent');
        }
        else{
            alert('no parent: window.opener');
        }
    });
    function Connector(msg){
        $('body').append(msg+'
');
    }
```